# How to add items in a list of tuples if the item is the same

Tags: list, python-3.x, tuples, polynomial-math

I'm trying to multiply two polynomials in Python3 (2x^3-3x^2+4x * 2x^2-3 = 4x^5-6x^4+2x^3+9x^2-12x) and to represent the polynomial I'm using a tuple `(exponent, variable)`, so the operation I described above would be: `[(3,2), (2,-3), (1,4)] * [(2,2), (0, -3)]`

And I got the next `list` as an answer: `[(5, 4), (3, -6), (4, -6), (2, 9), (3, 8), (1, -12)]`

That would represent: 4x^5-6x^3-6x^4+9x^2+8x^3-12x

But my problem is that I can't find a way to 'add' the tuples that have the same first element as you can see with the -6x^3 `(3, -6)` and 8x^3 `(3, 8)`.

Is there a "Pythonic" way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done in one line using [**`itertools.groupby()`**](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> [(exponent, sum(value for _, value in values)) for exponent, values in groupby(sorted(l, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))]
[(1, -12), (2, 9), (3, 2), (4, -6), (5, 4)]
```

Breaking it down into something more readable ([readability counts](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/))...

Import the tools:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>>
```

Declaring the input (you've already done this bit):

```
>>> l = [(5, 4), (3, -6), (4, -6), (2, 9), (3, 8), (1, -12)]
>>>
```

Before we can group, we need to sort (on the first item in the `tuple`):

```
>>> l_sorted = sorted(l, key=itemgetter(0))
>>>
```

And then group (again, by that first item):

```
>>> l_grouped = groupby(l_sorted, key=itemgetter(0))
>>>
```

Then create a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [**`sum`**](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)ming the values in the group (ignoring the key):

```
>>> [(exponent, sum(v for _,v in values)) for exponent, values in l_grouped]
[(1, -12), (2, 9), (3, 2), (4, -6), (5, 4)]
```

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted! Thank you very much, I don't need to tidy it up since it's just a homework for my algorithms class, and I couldn't get my code to work. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jose_Sunstrider: Had you posted the code that you couldn't get to work, we could have helped you fix it! You'd get a better sense of achievement from code you've written yourself!

Answer (score 2):

I would switch from lists to dictionaries. To make addition easier, I'd use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

poly = defaultdict(int)
```

And then add those tuples into the dictionary:

```
for exponent, variable in poly_list:
    poly[exponent] += variable
```

It sort of works:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> poly = defaultdict(int)
>>> 
>>> for poly_list in [[(1, 1)], [(1, 1)]]:
...     for exponent, variable in poly_list:
...         poly[exponent] += variable
... 
>>> poly
    defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {1: 2})
>>> poly.items()
    [(1, 2)]
```

Although personally, I would just make a `Polynomial` class:

```
class Polynomial(object):
    def __init__(self, terms=None):
        if isinstance(terms, dict):
            self.terms = terms
        else:
            self.terms = dict(terms) or {}

    def copy(self):
        return Polynomial(self.terms.copy())

    def __add__(self, other):
        result = self.copy()

        for e, c in self.terms.items():
            result[e] = self.get(e, 0) + c

        return result

    def __mul__(self, other):
        result = self.copy()

        for e1, c1 in self.terms.items():
            for e2, c2 in other.terms.items():
                result[e1 + e2] = self.get(e1, 0) * other.get(e2, 0)

        return result
```